# Why do I see `Dependency is not of a valid type` when I try to use this flake.nix

Tags: nix

I need to bind [`swag`](https://github.com/swaggo/swag) to a development environment at version 1.8.1.  I have a module which I believe builds it at that version:

```hs
# .deps/swag.nix
{ pkgs }:
{
  swag = pkgs.buildGoModule rec {
    name = "go-swag-1.8.1";
    version = "1.8.1";

    src = pkgs.fetchFromGitHub {
      owner = "swaggo";
      repo = "swag";
      rev = "v${version}";
      sha256 = "sha256-r19SYRHewbPL6S7bZGGqJk9QX8V9IxmRx3zyDeKGdn0=";
    };

    vendorHash = "sha256-QphjiJSQRULphWjrJ8RzrUblTDYL/fYoSNT3+g0tP48=";
    subPackages = [ "cmd/swag" ];
  };
}
```

I've included it in my `flake.nix` like so:

```hs
{
  inputs = {
    flake-utils.url = "github:numtide/flake-utils";
    nixpkgs.url = "github:nixos/nixpkgs";
  };

  outputs = { self, nixpkgs, flake-utils }:
    flake-utils.lib.eachDefaultSystem (system:
      let pkgs = import nixpkgs { inherit system; };
      in {
        devShells.default = pkgs.mkShell {
          packages = [ (import ./.deps/swag.nix { inherit pkgs; }) ];
        };
      });
}
```

When I run `nix develop` I see this error:

```
error: while calling the 'derivationStrict' builtin
pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix:375:7:
nativeBuildInputs           = elemAt (elemAt dependencies 0) 1;
^
depsBuildTarget             = elemAt (elemAt dependencies 0) 2;
error: Dependency is not of a valid type: element 1 of nativeBuildInputs for nix-shell
```

How can I debug this kind of error?

Answer (score 0):

`packages` in mkShell [ends up getting merged into nativeBuildInputs](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/d5766175de1b5b0e09f7d25c0d552fe4ee617a91/pkgs/build-support/mkshell/default.nix#L41) which is [a parameter on stdenv.mkDerivation](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/d5766175de1b5b0e09f7d25c0d552fe4ee617a91/pkgs/build-support/mkshell/default.nix#L37) which needs to be a list of derivations.

In your case, `nativeBuildInputs` was empty, so element 1 obviously refers to the only element supplied to `packages`.  In other cases the index in the error might be offset by the merge.

You can check what your module is actually exporting like so:

```
$ nix repl
nix-repl> pkgs = import<nixpkgs>{ }
nix-repl> import ./swag.nix { inherit pkgs; }
{ swag = «derivation /nix/store/frkbcnwr0kak5yvp847zq4w3d5nb84zk-go-swag-1.8.1.drv»; }
```

You'll notice that it's not actually a derivation, it's an attribute set containing a derivation. Modify the module to remove `swag =` and just let it export the output of `pkgs.buildGoModule` directly.

```hs
{ pkgs }:
pkgs.buildGoModule rec {
  name = "go-swag-1.8.1";
  version = "1.8.1";

  src = pkgs.fetchFromGitHub {
    owner = "swaggo";
    repo = "swag";
    rev = "v${version}";
    sha256 = "sha256-r19SYRHewbPL6S7bZGGqJk9QX8V9IxmRx3zyDeKGdn0=";
  };

  vendorHash = "sha256-QphjiJSQRULphWjrJ8RzrUblTDYL/fYoSNT3+g0tP48=";
  subPackages = [ "cmd/swag" ];
}
```

Notice the difference when you check it out in the repl:

```
nix-repl> import ./swag.nix { inherit pkgs; }
«derivation /nix/store/frkbcnwr0kak5yvp847zq4w3d5nb84zk-go-swag-1.8.1.drv»
```

Following this change, what you're supplying at `mkShell.packages` will actually be a list of derivations.